# Image of simply connected domains under polynomials

Tags: analysis

My task is to find a function $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with $T(x,y)=(P(x,y),Q(x,y))$, $P,Q$ non constant polynomials, such that there is $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ simply connected with $T(U)$ not simply connected.

With the answer given by @Marc van Leeuwen, I just realized that my previous attempt was right. Indeed, just take the complex exponential, then truncate it series expansion and consider the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approximate the cosine and sine functions sufficiently well on $[0,2\pi]$ by polynomial functions for appropriate polynomials $c,s\in\Bbb R[X]$. Then the polynomial map $T:(r,\phi)\mapsto(r.c[\phi],r.s[\phi])$ ought to do the job, taking for some small yet not too small value $0<\epsilon<1$ the set $U=[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\times[0,2\pi+\epsilon]$.